# How do I read the attributes for a dwarf in Dwarf Therapist?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In Dwarf Therapist, the attributes (Strength, Agility, Toughness, Endurance, Recuperation, and Disease Resistance) are displayed as following:

```
Strength
Very Strong (4581)
Strong (4413)
(3936)
Weak (3750)
Weak (3654)
Very Weak (3310)
Mighty (1995)
```

These are the tooltips from the following screenshot.

[image]

Clearly there's not a direct correlation between the words and the numbers. What exactly is it telling me?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of where this is? I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @Ullallulloo - There you go.

Comment: hmm...that's weird. Your numbers don't align with those on the wiki: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Attributes#Body_Attributes

Comment: @Ullallulloo - Yeah, that's why I'm so confused. Those numbers are copied directly from the actual tooltips for the first eight dwarves. I'm trying to make a squad of legendary warriors by using Skill Aethers (Masterwork mod), so I don't care about training aptitude, I just want to use my strongest and toughest dwarves. The problem is, I don't know whether I should be looking at the words or the numbers, since there doesn't seem to be any correlation between them.

Comment: I suspect that's experience for their current level.

Comment: I don't have a copy of DF and DT in front of me to check this with, but that number might be an indicator of how much experience that stat needs to level up.

Comment: If that were the case why would DT, when told to sort on strength, sort the list using that number?

Comment: @SaintWacko - Good question. Still going from memory because I didn't have a chance to check this last night - doesn't DT have a way to see an overview of a dwarf's stats and skills? I vaguely recall seeing something like that. IIRC, this will show the current level and EXP to level of the stats and skills for that dwarf. That might shed some light on what the numbers you're seeing mean.

Comment: @edsobo - It just says `Attribute: Strength, Value: 4612, Message: Very Strong`. Still doesn't explain why a dwarf with a value of 3310 is Very Weak, while a second dwarf with a value of 2036 is Unbelievably Strong.

Comment: Hm. [This screenshot from the DT Google Code page](http://dwarftherapist.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/img/dt_alpha.png) suggests that the number is supposed to be the value of the attribute, which suggests that the text descriptions you're seeing are not actually relevant to the numerical values.

Comment: @edsobo - Then what are the descriptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers are *absolute* values. 1250 is the median ("average" or no description) for Dwarves in the base game, 1000 the median for Humans.

The descriptions are *relative* values, as defined by the `PHYS_ATT_RANGE` and `MENT_ATT_RANGE` tag of the creature in question - or of its specific caste, if they differ from each other. Base game Dwarves don't differ, but Masterwork (1.9.5) in particular has several castes where the strength attribute is distributed differently.

---

For comparison, this is the default `CREATURE:DWARF` entry for strength:

```
[PHYS_ATT_RANGE:STRENGTH:450:950:1150:1250:1350:1550:2250]
```

These are from Masterwork 1.9.5 (abbrievated)

```
[PHYS_ATT_RANGE:200:700:900:1000:1100:1300:2000] -- default, not in the raws
[SELECT_CASTE:BERSERKER_MALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:BERSERKER_FEMALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:LEGION_MALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:LEGION_FEMALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:NECROFIGHTER_MALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:NECROFIGHTER_FEMALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:HOLYFIGHTER_MALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:HOLYFIGHTER_FEMALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:MAGICFIGHTER_MALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:MAGICFIGHTER_FEMALE]
    [PHYS_ATT_RANGE:STRENGTH:3000:3500:3750:4000:4250:4500:5000]
[SELECT_CASTE:NOBLE_MALE]
[SELECT_CASTE:NOBLE_FEMALE]
    [PHYS_ATT_RANGE:STRENGTH:700:1200:1400:1500:1600:1800:2000]
```

---

As to your specific example, almost every Dwarf in your list is from one of the fighter castes. For them, an absolute strength value of 3750 or less is already "weak", and 3500 or less even "very weak". The one "mighty" Dwarf with just 1995 absolute strength value is from one of the non-fighter, non-noble castes.

Comment: Oh, I see! So, just to clarify, the "weak" fighter dwarf will be more powerful in batle than the "mighty" non-fighter dwarf?

Comment: @SaintWacko: Exactly. Even the most gimped fighter caste Dwarf (at absolute strength of 3000) will be significantly stronger than any non-fighter caste Dwarf (at the maximum absolute strength of 2000 for all other castes).